# Why is my recursive variadic template not compiling?

Tags: c++, recursion, printing, variadic-templates

I would like to understand variadic templates a little bit better, which is why I wrote a function that takes any number of arguments, converts them to strings, adds them to a stringstream and prints that stream. My expectation would have been that the compiler jumps from `\\1` to `\\2` to `\\3` to `\\4` to `\\5` (compare code). But instead, it is stuck at `\\2`. Why is that?

Should the compiler not take the case that is "most matching" for a function invocation? My understanding of variadic templates is that you go from top to bottom and from base case to exception. I would have expected that, in `\\2`, when `print(strs, "this", " is ", "a ", "test ", 1, 2, 'a')` is called that this would go to `\\3`.

[Play with this code.](https://godbolt.org/z/k6nwYA)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


void print(std::string msg) // 5
{
    std::cout << msg;
}

template <class T>
void print(std::stringstream &strs, T t) // 4
{
    strs << std::to_string(t);
    print(strs.str());
}

template <class... Args, class T>
void print(std::stringstream &strs, T t, Args... args) // 3
{
    strs << t;
    print(strs, args...);
}

template <class... Args>
void print(Args... args) // 2
{
    std::stringstream strs();
    print(strs, args...);
}

int main()
{
    print("this", " is ", "a ", "test ", 1, 2, 'a'); // 1
}
```

Comment: Pretty unusual to provide the non-variadic parameters *after* the variadic ones...

Comment: "But instead, it is stuck at \\2" what does that mean? Do you get an error?

Comment: Check out the link I provided. The compiler will always try to use \\2. It is stuck there. It will not call the other functions and reaches its recursion depth of 900

Comment: Wait, you output one after another to a std::stringstream just to putput them to std::cout then anyway? Why not directly outputting to there?

Comment: Post is more educational than practical

Comment: When you provide `print`'s definition, you are missing `Printer::` in front of it (on the Godbolt version at least)

Comment: I interpret the compiler message differently. I dont see that this hits the limit for recursion depth. Maybe I am wrong, but anyhow better include the error in the question

Comment: What about a fold expression? `template <typename... Args> void print(Args... args) { (std::cout << ... << args); }`

Comment: I like that a lot @Aconcagua. Thank you. Still wondering why mine did not compile though...

Comment: `std::stringstream strs();` – that doesn't create an object, but declares a function returning a stringstream. As you then pass a function, not a stream, you call same overload again – recurring endlessly. You need to omit the parentheses...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vexing parse with:

`std::stringstream strs();` Function declaration

Use

`std::stringstream strs{};`

or

`std::stringstream strs;`

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/pzsNnx)

Comment: @User12547645: Not sure what you mean. Your code was mostly correct, except that `std::stringstream strs();` is not your expectation.